# I cannot save correctly plots from R

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

I created a boxplot on r using `boxplot`.

```
boxplot_nonorm= boxplot(log10(table_tissues_filtered_high+1), 
                        las=2, 
                        main= "Data not normalized",
                        col= "light green", )
```

Then I saved it as image and as pdf but the files generated are truncated. I report an example [image]

I cannot read the label names. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to increase the margin before you save your plot. You can change the margin with the `mar` in the `par()` `c(bottom, left, top, right)`

```
png(filename="figure.png", width=900, bg="white")
par(mar=c(10,6,4,1))
boxplot(mtcars, names = c(paste0("very_long_label",1:11)), las = 2)
dev.off()
```